# how to add column in table using doctrine symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to add column to existing table using the format yml.Added the new column 
entries into .yml file and running the command to generate entity

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities PLibBundle:Contact
```

By running this getting an error

> "No identifier / primary key specified for Entity"

here is my yml file:

```
Application\PLibBundle\Entity\Contact:
  type: entity
  table: null
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      length: null
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      nullable: false
      unique: false
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    firstName:
      type: string
      length: 255
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      nullable: false
      unique: false
    lastName:
      type: string
      length: 255
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      nullable: false
      unique: false
    companyText:
      type: string
      length: 255
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      nullable: true
      unique: false
    email:
      type: string
      length: 255
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      nullable: true
      unique: true
    hasCustomHeadshot:
      type: boolean
      length: null
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      nullable: false
      unique: false
    createdOn:
      type: datetime
      length: null
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      nullable: false
      unique: false
    updatedOn:
      type: datetime
      length: null
      precision: 0
      scale: 0
      nullable: false
      unique: false
  oneToOne:
    address:
      targetEntity: Application\PLibBundle\Entity\Address
      cascade:
        - remove
        - persist
      mappedBy: null
      inversedBy: null
      joinColumns:
        addressId:
          referencedColumnName: id
      orphanRemoval: true
  oneToMany:
    phoneNumberAssociations:
      targetEntity: Application\PLibBundle\Entity\ContactPhoneNumberAssociation
      cascade:
        - remove
        - persist
      mappedBy: contact
      inversedBy: null
      orphanRemoval: true
      orderBy: null
    subscriptionAssociations:
      targetEntity: Application\PLibBundle\Entity\ContactSubscriptionAssociation
      cascade:
        - remove
        - persist
      mappedBy: contact
      inversedBy: null
      orphanRemoval: true
      orderBy: null
  manyToOne:
    company:
      targetEntity: Application\PLibBundle\Entity\Company
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: null
      inversedBy: null
      joinColumns:
        companyId:
          referencedColumnName: id
      orphanRemoval: false
  lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist:
      - beforePersist
    preUpdate:
      - beforeUpdate
```

Answer (score 4):

The exception message pretty much solves this mystery, do you have something like this?

```
Contact:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 100
```

Comment: yes something similar to this , i want to one more extra field there and update entity is that possible

Comment: cant post my yml file in proper format , i have modified in the question , i am trying to add there

Comment: @LauriElias I think user (Rohan) has tried to add field as shown by you in your edits and he still seems to get the error

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the "id" key in your configuration.

You have:

```
Application\PLibBundle\Entity\Contact:
    type: entity
    table: null
    fields:
        id:
```

It should be:

```
Application\PLibBundle\Entity\Contact:
      type: entity
      table: null
      id:
          id:
```

Comment: @user3173000 That's what Lauri Elias meant. I wanted to add this clarification as a comment but couldn't.